# relational algebra

Tags: relational-database, relational-algebra

here is a example relation table I constructed from my relations.

```
Assignment   aID description
             1    A1
             2    A2
             3    A3  
#where aID is the unique key

Group        gID aID
             1    1
             2    1
             3    2 
             4    2  
             5    3
#where gID is the unique key , represent groups works on assignments.

Grader       gID  Username
              1    TA1
              2    TA2
              3    TA1
              4    TA2
              5    TA1
#where gID is the unique key and represent which TA is assign to grade a  group.

Result     gID, mark
            1    50
            2    60
            3    70
            4    80 
            5    90
#where gID is the unique key and present group's mark.
```

Find the grader who have marked every assignment , we say that grader has marked an assignment if they have given a grade on that assignment to at least one group.  From my example , TA1 should be reported. Any suggest approach to this question? Thanks in advance.

edit : gID is unique and use across all relation, implies that constrains

```
Group[aid] /subset assignment[aid]  
grader[gid] /subset group[gid]  
result[gid] /subset group[gid]
```

Comment: There isn't any table that says which grader has graded which assignments... the grader table has no relationships to any other tables... grader id (one of many gID's) isn't a foreign key in any of your other tables.

Comment: grader is associate with gID, and gID is unique and share across all relation. Each gID is associate with aID, mark, grader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note how simple things get when you name things clearly. gID in grader could easily have been the id of the grader... which also starts with g.

here is one way to achieve what I understand to be your solution. I have renamed things for clarity.

```
declare @Assignment  table (AssignmentID int, Description varchar(5))
insert into @Assignment
values
    (1,'A1'),
    (2,'A2'),
    (3,'A3')

declare @Group table (GroupID int, AssignmentID int)
insert into @Group
values
    (1,1),
    (2,1),
    (3,2),
    (4,2),
    (5,3)

declare @GroupGrader table (GroupID int, GraderName varchar(5))
insert into @GroupGrader
values
    (1,'TA1'),
    (2,'TA2'),
    (3,'TA1'),
    (4,'TA2'),
    (5,'TA1')

Declare @GroupResult table (GroupID int, Mark int)
insert into @GroupResult
values
    (1,50),
    (2,60),
    (3,70),
    (4,80),
    (5,90)

select gg.GraderName
from @Group g
    --inner join @Assignment a
    --  on a.AssignmentID = g.AssignmentID
    inner join @GroupGrader gg
        on g.GroupID = gg.GroupID
    --inner join @GroupResult gr
    --  on gr.GroupID = g.GroupID
group by gg.GraderName
having count(g.AssignmentID) = (select count(*) from @Assignment)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however I fail to see the need of join  Assignment with Group on aID. In group relation , every group already associate with a assignment with aID? Can you explain?

Comment: No, you are right. you don't actually need the join to Assignment for the solution to work. I have made the edit accordingly,

Answer (score 0):

It is not was very easy to understand, and we do not have 3NF here.
As I understand only one Grader can mark one group, and one group can have only one mark. In this case you can use this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Username FROM Grader WHERE Username NOT IN (
    SELECT grd.Username FROM Grader grd
    LEFT JOIN Assignment a ON (1=1)
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT grp.aId, grd.Username FROM [Group] grp
        LEFT JOIN Grader grd ON (grp.gID = grd.gID)
        LEFT JOIN Assignment a ON (grp.aID = a.aID)
        LEFT JOIN Result r ON (grp.aID = r.gID)) innerQuery
    ON (grd.Username = innerQuery.Username and a.aId = innerQuery.aId)
    WHERE innerQuery.aId is null);
```

Result:

```
Username
TA1
```